# matrix multiplication with a constant

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I Want to multiply the given 1x1x3 matrix with a constant value.

```
a= [[[1, 2, 3]]]
```

expected result is

```
a*3 = [[[3,6,9]]]
```

please help me to solve this

Comment: If that's the sort of stuff you need to do, it may be worth investing time into learning NumPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3]]])

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([[[1, 2, 3]]])

In [4]: a*3
Out[4]: array([[[3, 6, 9]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a= [[[1, 2, 3]]]
for i in range(len(a[0][0])):
    a[0][0][i] *= 3

print a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using list comprehensions:

```
>>> a = [[[1, 2, 3]]]
>>> b = [[x*3 for x in a[0][0]]]
>>> b
[[3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using pure Python:

```
a3 = [[[el * 3 for el in col] for col in row] for row in a]
```

This works with 3D matrices of any shape, not just 1x1x3.

However, if this is the sort of thing you need to do on a regular basis, I would encourage you to learn [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). Then you'll be able to write:

```
a3 = a * 3
```